# Let $a_n$ be a sequence, and assume that $\sup(a_n)=\infty$. Prove that there is a subsequence $b_k=a_{n_k}$ such that $b_k$ tends to ∞.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Can someone please help me?
I don't know where to start even these questions.

Let $a_n$ be a sequence, and assume that there is a subsequence $b_k=a_{n_k}$ such that $b_k$ tends to $\infty$. Prove that $\sup(a_n)=\infty$.

Let $a_n$ be a sequence, and assume that $\sup a_n=\infty$. Prove that there is a subsequence $b_k=a_{n_k}$ such that $b_k$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: We know that for any $n\in\mathbb N$, there exists $i\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_i>n$. Note that this is true for any subsequence $a_k,a_{k+1},...$ since there is an upper bound on $a_1,...,a_{k-1}$. So, let $b_i$ be an element of $a_n$ such that $b_i>i$ and $b_i$ appears after $b_{i-1}$ in the sequence (only when $i>1$).

Comment: You might want to start by writing down what $\sup(x_n)=\infty$ means.  Then you could experiment with applying that definition.  If you get started, I think people will help.

Comment: Here are two functions that you might find interesting.  I claim there exists a function $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb N$ such that $j=f(x)$ implies $a_j > x$.  Also consider the function $m:\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $m(n) = \max\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$.  You could think about how $f$ and $m$ could be used to generate a subsequence going to infinity.  (Similar to Don Thousand's comment.)

Comment: For the first part consider the sequence $0,1,0,2,0,4,0,8,........,0,2^k, 0,2^{k+1},......$.  For the second...  Well, if $n > N$ means $a_n > M$ then what if $2k >N$ what does that say about $a_{2k}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there is a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n_k}=\infty$. Then for each $M>0$ we may choose $k$ such that $a_{n_k}>M$. This implies that $\sup_n a_n\geqslant M$. Since $M$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\sup_n a_n = \infty$.

Assume now that $\sup_n a_n=\infty$. Choose $n_1$ such that $a_{n_1}>1$. Given $n_k$ such that $a_{n_k}>k$, choose $n_{k+1}>n_k$ such that $a_{n_{k+1}}>k+1$ (we can do this since $\sup_n a_n=\infty$). Then by construction, $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{n_k}=\infty$.